# Analysis of bisection search

Tags: algorithms, approximation, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/unit-1/lecture-3-problem-solving/

In the following video i'm interested from 42:04-43:30 (when he's talking about how many divisions there are) why he's divided the search space by $\epsilon^{2}$ (i.e $0.01^{2}$) in his complexity analysis of the bisection search method for finding a square root? Can anyone elaborate abit on this since he just skips it?

Comment: I don't see where there is a division by $\epsilon^2$. Is it on the board or something? Or is it only spoken?

Comment: Anyway, as for your question, if you start out with an interval of length $x$ and you want to reduce to an interval of length $2\epsilon$ (so that your final guess, which is the midpoint of your final interval, is with $\epsilon$ of the desired answer), then you need to take $n$ steps such that $2^{-n} \leq 2 \epsilon/x$, hence $n \geq -\log_2(2 \epsilon/x)=\log_2(x/\epsilon)-1$. I don't really see where $\epsilon^2$ comes into play here. So for instance his problem with $x=12345$ and $\epsilon=0.01$ will take about 20 steps.

Comment: It spoken by him. He divides his space of 12345 into chunks of size $0.01^{2}$ i then assume it's $\mathrm{log}(12345/0.01^{2})$ which gives him the approximation of 26 steps. He just didn't clarify why he divides by $0.01^{2}$ and it doesn't seem intuitive to me.

Comment: Also in your analysis i don't think its necessarily correct that the answer is the midpoint of the final interval, you can easily force this not to be the case by picking $\epsilon$ specifically

Comment: I think the square is either a mistake or your misunderstanding. I didn't find the exact point that you were talking about, though.

Comment: And I didn't say the *exact* answer is the midpoint of the final interval. The *approximate* answer, i.e. the return value of the numerical method, is usually taken to be the midpoint of the final interval. Not taking the midpoint of the last interval that you generate is a waste of accuracy.

Comment: The exact point i'm talking about is around 42 minutes, if you look at 42:00 and watch it for a couple of minutes you should hear him say it. Oh right sorry i misunderstood what you were saying. Yes once we reach an interval of length $2\epsilon$ of which the 'current guess' is the midpoint we are guaranteed to finish. Also by your calculations 20 steps should do it so why did his take 26?

Answer (score 1):

The stopping condition used in the video is a bit unusual for bisection, but would be very common for other techniques. He is stopping once $|g^2-x|<\epsilon$ where $g$ is the current guess. He is *not* stopping once $|g-\sqrt{x}|<\epsilon$, even though in bisection one can proceed this way. Here $|g^2-x|$ is called the forward error and $|g-\sqrt{x}|$ is called the backward error (I'll use these terms in what follows).

To determine the number of bisection steps required to have the forward error be less than $\epsilon$, one should determine or at least estimate the length of the interval around $\sqrt{x}$ where $|g^2-x|<\epsilon$. If $\epsilon$ is small enough, the half-length of this interval is approximately $\frac{\epsilon}{2\sqrt{x}}$. (I can think of two ways using calculus and one way using algebra to see this. Ask me if you don't understand.) In the example you have $x=12345$, and so you know that $\sqrt{x}$ is less than, say, $200$. So the half-length of the interval is at least $\frac{\epsilon}{400}$. So it is enough to use bisection to make the backward error be less than $\frac{\epsilon}{400}$. Beginning with an interval of length $x$ and taking the midpoint of the last interval generated to be the estimate, this takes at most $\log_2(x/(\epsilon/400))-1$ steps. This is less than 29. If I replace the $200$ with a better estimate like $112$, I can shave it down to 28 steps.

I do not really see how making the backward error less than $\epsilon^2$ ensures that the forward error is less than $\epsilon$; indeed, $(\sqrt{12345}+10^{-4})^2-12345>2 \cdot 10^{-2}$. Presumably this is either an error in the video or a misunderstanding on your part.

Comment: Thanks for the useful respons, perhaps the stopping condition $|g^{2}-x|$ is used because it doesn't presume knowledge of $\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: @PavanSangha In other methods, this is indeed why the forward error is used as a stopping condition: it can be explicitly calculated whereas the backward error cannot. In bisection, we usually use the backward error as a stopping condition, because bisection comes with a simple error estimate: the initial error is at most the half-length of the initial interval, and the bound on the error drops by a factor of $2$ at each iteration. So if the backward error tolerance is $\epsilon$ and the length of the initial interval is $L$ then you can stop in $\log_2(L/\epsilon)-1$ iterations.

Comment: In particular this means bisection can be implemented without any logic for stopping conditions, but just using a for loop with the number of iterations computed up front.

Comment: Never mind, no error, mixed myself up about something that was right in the first place.